# InfoPath publishing error for sharepoint form library

Tags: infopath, publishing, url

i want to publish my infopath form to sharepoint form library. I'm facing a site url problem.

```
the following URL is not valid: http://sitename
```

I know this is a well known problem but i try all of solution for this problem . I'm not still figuring out problem.

by the way, if i try the `"http://servername"` site it is published but the other web applications, which have hostname header and port number 80,  can not be published. I can also publish if i extend web apllication with a spesific port number like `"http://servername:12345".`

i tried below solution;

- it is a root site in the URL and it work on browser
- system event notification service stopped in server
- sitename entry added in hostfile
- all http verbs allowed as writing " * "

Answer (score 0):

ok i can figure out problem at the end.

i don't know still why it gives an error but adding the server name as an Internal URL in alternate access mapping and binding in iis, solved the case. However subject is still a problem for more than one web app. farm.